# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy

When I am attempting to develop NER model with CRF, After building my model I want to visualize test set as how it's understood by the model. But facing below error message, please anyone would you mind to fix it?

```
#Here is my feature extraction used
def word2features(sent, i):
    word = sent[i][0]
    postag = sent[i][1]

    features = {
        'bias': 1.0, 
        'word.lower()': word.lower(), 
        'word[-3:]': word[-3:],
        'word[-2:]': word[-2:],
        'word.isupper()': word.isupper(),
        'word.istitle()': word.istitle(),
        'word.isdigit()': word.isdigit(),
        'postag': postag,
        'postag[:2]': postag[:2],
    }
    if i > 0:
        word1 = sent[i-1][0]
        postag1 = sent[i-1][1]
        features.update({
            '-1:word.lower()': word1.lower(),
            '-1:word.istitle()': word1.istitle(),
            '-1:word.isupper()': word1.isupper(),
            '-1:postag': postag1,
            '-1:postag[:2]': postag1[:2],
        })
    else:
        features['BOS'] = True
    if i < len(sent)-1:
        word1 = sent[i+1][0]
        postag1 = sent[i+1][1]
        features.update({
            '+1:word.lower()': word1.lower(),
            '+1:word.istitle()': word1.istitle(),
            '+1:word.isupper()': word1.isupper(),
            '+1:postag': postag1,
            '+1:postag[:2]': postag1[:2],
        })
    else:
        features['EOS'] = True
    return features
def sent2features(sent):
    return [word2features(sent, i) for i in range(len(sent))]
def sent2labels(sent):
    return [label for token, postag, label in sent]
def sent2tokens(sent):
    return [token for token, postag, label in sent]
```

To get tokens with their respective named entity and POS tags

```
class SentenceGetter(object):
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.n_sent = 1
        self.data = data
        self.empty = False
        agg_func = lambda s: [(w, p, t) for w, p, t in zip(s['Word'].values.tolist(), 
                                                           s['POS'].values.tolist(), 
                                                           s['Tag'].values.tolist())]
        self.grouped = self.data.groupby('Sentence #').apply(agg_func)
        self.sentences = [s for s in self.grouped]
        
    def get_next(self):
        try: 
            s = self.grouped['Sentence: {}'.format(self.n_sent)]
            self.n_sent += 1
            return s 
        except:
            return None
getter = SentenceGetter(df)
sentences = getter.sentences


X = [sent2features(s) for s in sentences]
y = [sent2labels(s) for s in sentences]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
```

In the below code snippet I want to visualize performance of the model in the test set of the dataset

```
#Error triggering code

i = np.random.randint(0, X_test[0]) # choose a random number between 0 and len(X_test)
p = crf.predict(np.array([X_test[i]]))
p = np.argmax(p, axis=-1)
true = np.argmax(y_test[i], -1)

print("Sample number {} of {} (Test Set)".format(i, X_test[0]))
#For Visualization
print("{:15}||{:5}||{}".format("Word", "True", "Predicted"))
print(10 * "=")
for w, t, pred in zip(X_test[i], true, p[0]):
    if w != 0:
        print("{:15}: {:5} {}".format(words[w-2], X_test[t], X_test[pred]))
```

```
#Below is full traceback message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-6dcda3331198> in <module>
----> 1 i = np.random.randint(0, X_test[0]) # choose a random number between 0 and len(X_test)
      2 p = crf.predict(np.array([X_test[i]]))
      3 p = np.argmax(p, axis=-1)
      4 true = np.argmax(y_test[i], -1)
      5 

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint()

_bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32()

_bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32_broadcast()

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int
```

Comment: It looks like `X_test[0]` is a `dict`. Can you debug this to see what value it is? It's most likely you need to convert dict to int.

Comment: Thanks, surely it is in the form of dict but I have encoded to convert mine categorical data to int form using code:   ```from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
X = df.drop('Tag', axis=1)
enc.fit(X)
OrdinalEncoder()
enc.transform(X)``` but it returns the same error